# Using JSMol with JSME on a React Application

Tags: reactjs

I am currently making a web-application for chemical structure generation. I was so far using JSME to generate 2d structures and using those for molecular prediction.

I came across the JSMol/JMol library and wanted to integrate it along with my JSME to allow users to also view the molecules in 3d on a button click.

I found several resources online but all seem to be using Java Applet but it appears that Applet does not seem to pair well with React (correct me if I am wrong, thanks).

Does anyone know what I can do? How can I use the JSMol along with my 2d JSME Editor to convert the 2d molecules to a 3d representation? Also, is there any react npm library that allows for that?

Here are some resources and implementations of JSMol I found online but all seem to use Applet.

https://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jsmol/jsmetest2.htm

https://jmol.sourceforge.net/demo/JSME_2d3d.html

This is the code I used inside React to implement the JSME Editor:

```
            <div style={{ display: "none" }} id="jsmestyle">
              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <Jsme
                  height="350px"
                  width="550px"
                  options="oldlook,star"
                  disabled={loading}
                  onChange={logSmiles}
                  // smiles={smiles}
                />
              </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebtSw.jpg)